# animation callback architecture and time measuring when using HTLM5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, clock, requestanimationframe

I'm doing some animation with Canvas now, and will be preparing a system for the artists to use to make interactive animations. I'll be using my own timeline as the scenes will be created from some declarative non-js input. My question is: what's the right way to handle the per frame callback and time measurement? In audio (my real-time background), the rule is that there should be only only *one* master callback method called by the audio system, and any other objects register with it somehow. And *all* time calculations are done by counting sample ticks of this callback so there is one and only one true clock source (no asking the system clock for anything, just count samples). I assumed this is what I should do in my canvas app but I'm seeing examples in books and sites where multiple objects use requestAnimationFrame, and then check the frame rate by using date objects to measure elapsed time. Am I off base in thinking one master callback is still the most elegant way to go? And can I rely on measuring time in frame ticks assuming I'm getting really 60fps if using requestAnimationFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Your instinct is valid...route all your animation through one `requestAnimationFrame` loop to keep your animations well coordinated.

The current version of `requestAnimationFrame` in modern browsers automatically receives a highly accurate timestamp parameter based on the `performance` object.  That timestamp is accurate to 1/1000th of a millisecond.

You cannot rely on counting the number of calls ("ticks") to the animation loop.  The loop will be deferred if the prior loop's animation code has not completed or if the system is busy.  Therefore, you are not guaranteed 60fps.  You are guaranteed the browsers best efforts to get you 60fps.

Bottom line: requestAnimationFrame is not guarenteed to be called at 60fps intervals so you are left with 2 basic animation alternatives:

- Use the timestamp to calculate an elaped time and position your objects based on elapsed time.
- Increment a counter with each call to the animation loop and postion your objects based on the counter.

Comment: Thanks! So to do math for calculating how far a point should move in a tick, is it safe to assume it averages out to 60fps or does one need to use timestamps on every tick to figure out how far the point should move?

Comment: Well, if drawing your animation takes more than 1/60 of a second then you will not get 60fps.  It's not safe to assume an average of 60fps--you have to test the frame rate for each designed animation.  Using timestamps will position objects correctly relative to elapsed time.  Using a tick-counter will position objects correctly relative to #-of-elapsed-loops.  Both will "stutter" occasionally.